# Números quase primos

Tags: c, matemática

Tenho uma duvida em C, eu sei verificar se um numero é primo, porém, quase primo não sei.. como eu faço?

Segue a parte do código funcionando! Porém, só verificando se é primo.. o quase primo não roda

```
//  quasePrimos.c
// 
//
//  Created by Braynner Teixeira on 12/09/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Braynner Teixeira. All rights reserved.
//


#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num, i, controle=0;


    printf("Informe um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num > 1)
    {


         // Dividir o numero informado por todos os numeros que estao entre ele e 1.

        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {

            if (num % i == 0) 
            controle++;

        }


           if (controle == 2) {


            printf("O numero %d e um numero primo!\n", num);


        }
        else if (controle == 2 && controle*controle == num) {

                printf("O numero %d e quase primo!\n", num);

            }else {

            printf("O numero %d nao e um numero primo!\n", num);
        }

    }

    else if (num == 1 ) printf("O numero nao é primo e nem quase primo!");

}
```

Comment: Qual o conceito de número quase primo?

Comment: Todo número inteiro maior do que 1 tem pelo menos dois divisores positivos: ele mesmo e 1. As únicas exceções são 0 e 1

Comment: Jefferson Quesado, eu dou o numero 15, e daí o produto dele: 3*5 é igual a ele mesmo.

Comment: 16 é quase primo? Eu acho que não, pode me confirmar? E 4 também não é quase primo, confere?

Comment: Isso, nenhum deles são!

Comment: [Aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_prime) diz que 16 é quase primo (para `k=4`) @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: @bfavaretto quadrados perfeitos de números compostos? Ok, então preciso estudar mais

Comment: Essa é minha duvida.. cruel..

Comment: @Jefferson E eu então? Nunca tinha ouvido falar em "quase" primos até agora. Não boto a mão no fogo pelo que está na Wikipedia, nem entendi totalmente.

Comment: Um numero quase primo, ou semi primo, é aquele que é o produto de dois números primos. Por exemplo 4, 6, 9, etc... (2*2, 2*3, 3*3)

Comment: Pelo oque sei, é o produto de dois valores primos

Comment: @Cleber Então seria o que diz a Wikipédia limitado a k=2?

Comment: @bfavaretto, não é limitado. Nesse caso, um "quase primo" é produto de **qualquer numero primo** multiplicado por **qualquer numero primo**.

Comment: Na pergunta dizia o seguinte: um número é quase primo se e somente se ele pode ser descrito como um produto de dois primos distintos.

Ex: 15 (= 5*3) é quase primo, já 2 e 4 não são.

Comment: Bem, o conceito de quase primo na pergunta é o [2-quasi-primo](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_semiprimo). Então, @bfavaretto , é o conceito da Wiki em inglês dado `k=2`. Essa conversa do `k` é uma generalização

Comment: Semi Primo é a mesma coisa de Quase Primo? eu pensava que não!! Semi Primo era o produto de dois primos e Quase era de primos distintos..

Comment: @BraynnerTeixeira segundo as pesquisas de Wikipedia das pessoas dessa thread, não importa os números serem distintos os iguais. E semi primo seria um caso específico de quasi-primo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um número `k`-quasi-primo é dado por ele ser composto por um produto de primos com `k` fatores. Exemplos:

- `15 = 3 * 5` é 2-quasi-primo,
- `9 = 3 * 3` é 2-quasi-primo,
- `16 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2` é 4-quasi-primo,
- `5 = 5` é 1-quasi-primo.

No caso, o conceito quase primo é equivalente a 2-quasi-primo. Ou seja, `k = 2`.

Para isso, temos de descobrir quais são os fatores primos e quantas vezes eles são usados em cada número. Seu algoritmo está muito próximo da detecção de um número `k`-quasi-primo. Vou ajustar de tal modo que o valor da variável `k` indica qual "*grau*" de quasi-primalidade o número `n` possui:

```
int k = 0;
int i = 2;
while (n > 1) {
 while (n % i == 0) {
   k++;
   n /= i;
 }
 i++;
}
```

No caso, para detectar com quasi-primalidade `k=2`, basta verificar se `k` é 2 no final da execução. Também podemos abortar o laço antes da sua conclusão, caso se detecte um novo fator primo e `k` já valer 2, podemos retornar falso. Desse jeito:

```
int num = n; // como vou deteriorar o valor de n, vou guardar uma cópia para futura impressão
int quasi_primalidade = 2;
int k = 0;
int i = 2;
while (n > 1) {
 while (n % i == 0) {
   k++;
   n /= i;
   if (k > quasi_primalidade) {
     // pode ser um return se estiver em uma função
     goto FIM_LACOS;
   }
 }
 i++;
}
FIM_LACOS:
if (k == quasi_primalidade) {
  printf("O numero %d e um numero primo!\n", num);
} else {
  printf("O numero %d nao eh um numero primo =(\n", num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que no primeiro if a condição é `(controle == 2)`.
Logo, ele sempre vai entrar ali e nunca vai entrar no `else if (controle == 2 && controle*controle == num)` porque se o controle for 2, ele já vai para a primeira condição.

Para resolver este problema, tente inverter as condições:

```
if (controle == 2 && controle*controle == num) {
    printf("O numero %d e quase primo!\n", num);
}
else if (controle == 2) {
    printf("O numero %d e um numero primo!\n", num);
}
else {
    printf("O numero %d nao e um numero primo!\n", num);
}
```